# Prevent use of static modifier

Tags: java

I'm making a game where players have to write their own class to control the on-screen units. However, I want to prevent them from using static variables inside the player class so that their units have to communicate information via a communication system I have developed (i.e transmitting 1s and 0s) rather than just accessing the static "unitsTargeted" variable or whatever else it might be. Can I prevent them from using static modifiers somehow?

Comment: Not really, unless you want to write your own compiler.

Comment: Offload the behavior part to an abstract class or interface which the players will have to implement. Prevent them from touching the Players class.

Comment: It's unclear as to why a `static` variable isn't valid in the players class. If they make a non-static `unitsTargeted` variable would that not also be bad?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That depends. If you have no control over the source code or the run environment, then you cannot stop them from compiling what they want nor from having that executed.

If you have control over the build (ie: the source gets sent to a system you controlled and you control the compilation), then you could build a custom compiler.

If you control the run environment in some fashion, you could inspect the supplied class to see what it contains. You could use some byte-code tool, or better yet just use reflection API and check if any of the members are static. Once you use reflection to get a list of members, iterate over them and check their `isStatic`. If the class contains any static members, you could reject it.

In  your case, since you are uploading classes to a server from clients, you could check it simply by using Java's reflection API. If the clients are submitting source code, then you will need to compile it first, though I assume you do that anyway before you use it.

Here is a test case I just ran:

```
package test.tmp;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.lang.reflect.Modifier;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class StaticChecker
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        for(Class c : new Class[]{StaticChecker.class, ClassWithStatics.class, ClassWithoutStatics.class})
        {
            System.out.println("For " + c + "...");

            boolean hasStatic = hasStaticMembers(c);
            System.out.println("\tIt contains static members: " + hasStatic);

            if(hasStatic)
            {
                System.out.println("\tThe static members are:");
                for(String s : checkStaticMembers(c))
                    System.out.println("\t\t" + s);
            }
        }
    }

    public static boolean hasStaticMembers(Class c)
    {
        return checkStaticMembers(c).size() > 0;
    }

    public static List<String> checkStaticMembers(Class c)
    {
        List<String> staticMemberNames = new ArrayList<String>();

        for(Field field : c.getDeclaredFields())
            if(Modifier.isStatic(field.getModifiers()))
                staticMemberNames.add(field.toString());

        for(Method method : c.getDeclaredMethods())
            if(Modifier.isStatic(method.getModifiers()))
                staticMemberNames.add(method.toString());

        return staticMemberNames;
    }
}

class ClassWithStatics
{
    public static int N = 3;
    private static String S = "?";

    private int n;

    void f() { System.out.println("f()"); }
    static void g() { System.out.println("g()"); }
    public static void h() { System.out.println("h()"); }
}

class ClassWithoutStatics
{
    int a;
    String b;
    void f() { System.out.println("f()"); }
}
```

When I run the above test, I get the following output:

```
For class test.tmp.StaticChecker...
    It contains static members: true
    The static members are:
        public static void test.tmp.StaticChecker.main(java.lang.String[])
        public static java.util.List test.tmp.StaticChecker.checkStaticMembers(java.lang.Class)
        public static boolean test.tmp.StaticChecker.hasStaticMembers(java.lang.Class)
For class test.tmp.ClassWithStatics...
    It contains static members: true
    The static members are:
        public static int test.tmp.ClassWithStatics.N
        private static java.lang.String test.tmp.ClassWithStatics.S
        static void test.tmp.ClassWithStatics.g()
        public static void test.tmp.ClassWithStatics.h()
For class test.tmp.ClassWithoutStatics...
    It contains static members: false
```

Please note that what you are doing can be dangerous and you should be very careful to limit what code executed server-side can do. All someone needs to do to ruin your day is submit a class which deletes files or installs unwanted files or any other nefarious action.

Comment: This sounds like what I need to do. Can you point me towards any good resources regarding how to practically implement this? My plan is for players to upload their classes via a webpage to a server I control, where my source code will run the game and return the results. So I theoretically should be able to check if players are using any static variables prior to running the source code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do not to use static variable in your program, or if you really need one, make it ThreadLocal and keep it on a thread which is not accessible from the user classes.

If you want your program to be relatively safe you should also build some kind of class validator which will make sure those classes use only allowed classes, a very short white list of allowed classes.

You can use ASM to make such validator.

Comment: Thank you, this sounds like something I will need to do. I'll check out ASM.